# SOQL with GROUP BY & ORDER BY

Tags: soql

I'm trying to get the following lines to function however receive a return of

> MALFORMED_QUERY: Ordered field must be grouped or aggregated: Line_Number__c.

What is wrong here?

```
SELECT PricebookEntry.Name, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice,Product_Line_Description__c, Item_Type_Dependent__c, Line_Number__c 
FROM OpportunityLineItem 
WHERE Item_Type__c = 'SCS' AND Product_or_Labor__c = 'Product' AND OpportunityId = '0060z00002xZhV' 
GROUP BY Item_Type_Dependent__c
ORDER BY Line_Number__c ASC
```

Answer (score 4):

When you're querying for an aggregate result, each row in the result is a combination of rows that have the same value for fields in the `group by` expression.  So, the aggregate of multiple records does not have one `Line_Item_Number__c` value to return.  Each record has one, but the grouping of those records does not.  You can add additional fields to a `group by` statement separated by commas, e.g. `group by Item_Type_Dependent__c, Line_Item_Number__c`, which will cause the system to first group by `Item_Type_Dependent__c`, and then for each record in that grouping group them again by `Line_Item_Number__c`.  You could then order the result by `Line_Item_Number__c` since every row would necessarily have a `Line_Item_Number__c` column, although multiple rows could have the same value for `Line_Item_Number__c` if they have different `Item_Type_Dependent__c`.

Note that you will run into the same problem with all the other fields you have in your select statement, so you may want to reconsider what data you are actually hoping to get back to figure out if you should be using an aggregate query or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply-- to clarify then my goal is not achievable then?

What I'm attempting to query here is a table of products and some values pertaining to each row and I'd like to group by Item_Type_Dependent__c value and then order that by Line_Item_Number__c (which is simply a number field that represents the row)

Comment: @charltonhua Think about it this way - if you have two records with `Item_Type_Dependent__c` = 1, and they have `Line_item_Number__c` = 2 and 4, should that row come before or after another row with one record with `Line_Item_Number__c` = 3?  You could order by `MIN(Line_Item_Number__c)`.

Comment: thanks for the info, looks like none of this will work since the fields being selected are native currency fields and when using GROUP BY method, we must group all fields selected I guess